# Can an indexed view be made to handle this user rating scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].Person
    (
       PersonID  NT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
       Name      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    )

    CREATE TABLE [Resource].[Resource]        
    (
       ResourceID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,           
       Title      VARCHAR(500)  NOT NULL,        
    )

    CREATE TABLE [Resource].[ResourceRating]
    (
       ResourceRatingID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,

       ResourceID       INT NOT NULL,     --Resource being rated
       PersonID         INT NOT NULL,     --Person who gave the rating

       IsThumbUp        BIT NOT NULL,     --Like/Dislike        
     )
     GO
```

Which allows a `Person` to rate a `Resource`.
My goal is to perform searches on resources that can be sorted by "Rating" and "# of likes". My thought was to create a view to help with this:

```
CREATE VIEW [Resource].[vResource] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT 
         s.[ResourceID]
        ,s.[Title]
        ,s.[Likes]
        ,s.[Dislikes]
        ,[Rating] =  CASE WHEN (s.[Likes] + s.[Dislikes]) = 0 THEN 100   --Prevent divide by zero when no ratings exist
                          ELSE CEILING(((s.[Likes] / (s.[Likes] + s.[Dislikes])) * 100)) 
                     END
    FROM
    (
       SELECT 
          r.[ResourceID]
         ,r.[Title]
         ,[Likes]    = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Resource].[ResourceRating] rr WHERE rr.[ResourceID]=r.[ResourceID] AND rr.[IsThumbUp]=1)
         ,[Dislikes] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Resource].[ResourceRating] rr WHERE rr.[ResourceID]=r.[ResourceID] AND rr.[IsThumbUp]=0)  
        FROM [Resource].[Resource] r
    ) s
GO
```

I'm a bit concerned about the performance of querying against the view though. My question is... is there a better way to do this? I can't index the view as written but I'm not sure how else to get the rating in the view to be sortable.

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to index a view that delivers you the results you want. But you can index a view that provides the computationally expensive parts.

At the heart your query is a `GROUP BY ResourceID` of the `ResourceRating` table. You want to extract "rating statistics" for each resource. You can index this part:

```
SELECT
    ResourceID,
    SUM(IIF(IsThumbUp = 1, 1, 0)) AS IsThumbUpCount,
    SUM(IIF(IsThumbUp = 0, 1, 0)) AS IsThumbDownCount
FROM dbo.ResourceRating
GROUP BY ResourceID
```

How to combine this with re `Resource` table? Either join "at runtime", or pull the join into the view. I don't memorize all the indexed view constraints so I don't know whether the last option is possible. I think so.

My thinking pattern regarding indexes views is: Can I fit the expensive parts I want to optimize either into a single `GROUP BY` or into a series of `INNER JOIN`'s? This is basically what indexed views offer. If I can match that pattern I can used indexed views.

Comment: That sounds good to me. If the Group BY resource query can be made an indexed view...does what do you the indedx should be on. Just resourceID or all fields?

Comment: On ResID because it is the logical PK for that view. It is unique. You must have a unique CI anyway. The CI includes all fields.